# How to get a template instance id?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to set an id for a template instance. One that survives a hot code push.
I tried adding the id to a "data-id" attribute on the template's firstNode, but it's lost when a hot code push happens.

The goal is to save the state of the template in a session variable named after the template id. On the template rendered event I would check for that session variable and if it has the info I would restore the state of the template when a hot code push occurs.

**Update**
This is for a package so the id has to be a random number.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use session for that. `ReactiveDict` (from `reactive-dict` package) now supports data migration which survives hot code pushes
(look [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/reactive-dict/reactive-dict.js#L21)).
The only thing you need to do is provide a unique name for your reactive dict instance

```
Template.yourTemplateName.created = function () {
  this.myState = new ReactiveDict('myUniqueId');
}
```

This will only work - of course - unless you have multiple concurrent instances of  your template. Also note that this solution will not guarantee state survival after user forces page reload. If you need to support more sophisticated behavior patterns then you probably won't get away with using cookies or local-storage-based solutions.

Comment: That's the problem, I'm trying to save a random ID for the template instance so I can retrieve the state after a hot code push. Your example assumes I already have the ID.

Comment: Any source on the claim "ReactiveDict now supports data migration which survives hot code pushes"? [Comments in the code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/reactive-var/reactive-var.js#L10) disagree.

Comment: @PeppeL-G Good point! I've forgotten to add the proper reference.

Comment: @Manuel So I assume that the reason to use random IDs is that you want multiple instances at the same time. Is that correct?

Comment: @apendua, sorry, I read "ReactiveDict" as "ReactiveVar" ^^' Anyway, thanks for the clarification. Side note: seems like they haven't updated the readme file, because it says: "It provides all of the functionality of the Session object [...], except that its contents are not saved across Hot Code Push client code updates".

Comment: @apendua That's correct, there can be multiple instances and I don't have any context to differentiate them.